# How to convert HTML character references in MySQL?

Tags: html, mysql, utf-8

In one old database we have HTML character references like: `&#23637;&#35272;` how can I convert them into valid UTF8 characters (`&#23637;&#35272;` -> `展览`)?

I know that e.g. PHP func `html_entity_decode` does this, but amount of data is to big to pass this back and fourth to PHP

Match all by regexp, cast to int and then cast to code-point? Is it possible?

Comment: They are not UTF8 literals but (SGML, HTML, XML) character references (which are independent of character encoding).

Comment: A database dump (can be done per table with mysqldump), on which one can run a conversion. Converting need not be done with PHP, also Java with StringEscapeUtils is possible (more robust). Or whatever.

Comment: I understand that :) just used wrong naming. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

As Joop Eggen says, I would make a **dump** of the table that you need to convert and then i would convert the file with bash program **recode**

Example:

dumping the db into mydb.sql file

```
mysqldump -uroot -p mydb > mydb.sql
```

converting html entities to utf8

```
recode html..utf8 mydb.sql
```

now mydb.sql is converted